# Is there any way to set the value of data-value attribute dynamically in html tags?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using attributes in HTML tags to control data. how should I set data-val value dynamically?

I'm setting up a new configuration for an application. according to this configuration, I need to set the `data-Val` attribute dynamically in the `<Select>` tag.
when I write `data-val="true"`, It works Ok. but when set it's value dynamically, It doesn't work. 
Note that the type of `tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()` is boolean .

```
<div class="k-dropdown-wrap editor-select-width">
   <select
    multiple="multiple"
    class="k-dropdown 
    TabOnEnter"
    tabindex="6"
    id="insuranceCertificateEdit_GoodID"
    name="insuranceCertificateEdit.GoodID"
    data-bind=" options: 
    tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().GoodSelectItems, 
    enable:tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().FinalRegister() 
    == false,
    optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue : 'ID',
    selectedOptions: 
    tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().GoodIds, 
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"
    data-val="tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()"
    data-val-required="Fill this field!">
   </select>
</div>
<span
  class="field-validation-valid"
  data-valmsg-
  for="insuranceCertificateEdit.GoodID"
  data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
```

I expect when I use `tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()` for `data-val` It works by it's value .

Comment: Of course you can set the name and value of any tag when you are rendering the page, and you can also set them via jquery. What am I not understanding about your question?

Comment: even I use data-val= 
tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()

Comment: How did you try to set the value dynamically?

Comment: how can I use jquery here?

Comment: t.niese !  data-val= 
"tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()" even without ""

Comment: You do not mention that you use any template library or any other library that would execute that as code. So with the given information you just set `data-val` to the string `tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()`.

Comment: What makes you think "tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods()" is boolean? you are assigning the text as the value.

Comment: Nawed Khan ! I assigned (true/false) to tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods() in My .js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must eval your string in `data-val` attribute and call it as a function!

probably in your `$(document).ready()` event :

```
var jsCode = $("#insuranceCertificateEdit_GoodID").attr("data-val");
eval(jsCode);
var resultData = eval(jsCode);
```

And set result in any attribute you want.

Comment: I have the value but I can't use this value for data-val.

Comment: tisApp.insuranceCertificateVM.insuranceCertificate().HasForbiddenGoods() in console return (true OR false)